# How can i set this JSON with dynamic keys in POJO and get data from it in Android JAVA?

Tags: java, android, json

I am developing an e-commerce app and I am getting this JSON data from API.

{"status": 0, "data": {"stores": {"test-5": {"name": "Test 5", "locality": {"name": "Some place B", "id": 2}, "cover": "IMAGE-URL-HERE"}, "test-2": {"name": "Test 2", "locality": {"name": "Some place A", "id": 2}, "cover": "IMAGE-URL-HERE"}}}, "action": [["DATA", "stores"]]}

I have created some POJO for this data too

```
public class PartnerStoreMainPOJO {
    @SerializedName("partnerstore")
    @Expose
    private PartnerStoresPOJO partnerstore;
    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The data
     */
    public PartnerStoresPOJO getPartnerStore() {
        return partnerstore;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param partnerstore
     * The data
     */
    public void setPartnerStore(PartnerStoresPOJO partnerstore) {
        this.partnerstore = partnerstore;
    }
}
```

//-------------
public class PartnerStoresPOJO {

```
@SerializedName("partnerstoredetail")
@Expose
private Map<String, PartnerStoreDetailPOJO> partnerstoredetail;

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The feeds
 */
public Map<String, PartnerStoreDetailPOJO>  getpartnerstoredetail() {
    return partnerstoredetail;
}
/**
 *
 * @param partnerstoredetail
 * The feeds
 */
public void setpartnerstoredetail(Map<String, PartnerStoreDetailPOJO> partnerstoredetail) {
    this.partnerstoredetail = partnerstoredetail;
}
```

}
 //----------------

public class PartnerStoreDetailPOJO {

```
@SerializedName("partnerstorelocality")
@Expose
private Map<String, PartnerStoreLocalityPOJO> partnerstorelocality;


@SerializedName("cover")
@Expose
private String cover;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

/**
 * @return The name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name The name
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return The cover
 */
public String getCover() {
    return cover;
}

/**
 * @param cover The address
 */
public void setCover(String cover) {
    this.cover = cover;
}

public Map<String, PartnerStoreLocalityPOJO> getpartnerstorelocality() {
    return partnerstorelocality;
}

public void setpartnerstorelocality(Map<String, PartnerStoreLocalityPOJO> partnerstorelocality) {
    this.partnerstorelocality = partnerstorelocality;
}
```

}

//----------------

```
public class PartnerStoreLocalityPOJO {
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * The name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The id
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

//---------------

Amd i am using volley library. This is my java code-

```
public void onResultReceived(String response, String tag_json_obj) {
        if (tag_json_obj.equals(LOCALITY_SET)){

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                String data=jsonObject.getString("data");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("EXCEPTN",e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

I am using that data string.

Comment: Are you extracting the array in data or trying to convert the complete JSON? i mean the top level pojo should have status and data. Below data the other objects. Show some of the Java code your using including imports of libraries.

Comment: If you can ask the API developers : "data": {"stores": can you ask them of this is a array or map or something else?

Comment: Using Iterator, you can get the key of every object of JSON. Get the key and use it for fetching next objects.

Comment: The API is written in Django python and its map. I updated,  my java code to please recheck the question.

Comment: @stutikasliwal i have already tried that way but my json can not convert into JsonArray and it throws an exception of cannot cast to JsonArray.

Comment: But why you are converting it into JSONArray?

Comment: Then how can i fetch every key and its particular value and set them into my POJO?

Comment: Simply navigate through the Iterators and its subIterators for every single object. And turn by turn add into your pojo. You don't need to convert it into JSONArray, doing conversion it may complicate your code.

Comment: Let me show you an example in below answer, You can try it once. Or you can change it as per your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it once: Do changes accordingly, It can give you a direction for your query.

```
public void convertJSON(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        try {
            JSONObject object = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");

            Iterator<String> iter = object.keys();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                String key = iter.next();
                Object value = object.get(key);

                JSONObject obj2 = object.getJSONObject(key);
                //set key to POJO

                Iterator<String> iter2 = obj2.keys();
                while (iter2.hasNext()) {
                    String key2 = iter2.next();
                    //....so on
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: but doing nested loop may slow my app ... is this the only way to do this?

Comment: Yes but the JSON is also nested, You can follow your way too. With the help of key of each object convert the rest of the value into JSONArray `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();` and `jsonArray.put(obj2.get(key));` in Iterator

Comment: Sure. All the best